# AWS lambda handler causing code to not show, no response

Tags: python, web-scraping, aws-lambda

I am trying to get this function to work in lambda, I am able to get this call to work properly without `def lambda_handler(event, context):` but with it it does not do anything.(No Errors).

Currently working in VS Code.

Is there something I am missing in my code?

Project goal: Scrape data with simple function in lambda, move to DB. Recall and send to user behind a paywall in a structured way.

```
import json
from zenrows import ZenRowsClient


def lambda_handler(event, context):

client = ZenRowsClient("197bb953a9c846cff9xxxxxxx7cbaxxxxxe033", retries=1)
url = "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/softbank"

response = client.get(url, params={"autoparse": True})


print(response.text)
```

Comment: your code inside the handler should be indented, but that would show an error, what output is given when you run it? You say no errors, but does it print your ```response.text```?

Comment: It does not, after some research I found out that I don't have it containerized correctly. But, I suppose I am not quite sure how to best do that.

Comment: Are you using one of the default python runtimes or are you deploying an ECS container?  How are you testing the function?

Comment: I am using a default runtime. Is a container better to be using? 

I was testing the base code in VS code.

Comment: Using the default is fine for your use case. How are you testing the Lambda function? What is the output when you test the Lambda, there will be at a minimum the request ID and duration.